# Linking to a .so library in cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++, cmake-gui, libmosquitto

I have a libmosquittopp.so in /usr/lib folder.
The mosquittopp.h is inside /usr/include folder.

I like to link to my project to that lib.

So my CMakeLists.txt file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(MosquittoTest)
# The version number.
set (VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (VERSION_MINOR 0)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

# Linked libariries
#For MQTT
#location of raspicam's cmake file is /usr/src/raspicam-0.1.3/build
link_directories(/usr/lib)
target_link_libraries (MosquittoTest  mosquittopp)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(MosquittoTest MosquittoTest.cpp)

# add the install targets
install (TARGETS MosquittoTest DESTINATION bin)
install (FILES MosquittoInterface.h DESTINATION include)
```

But when I configure in ccmake GUI, I have error as

```
Cannot specify link ibraries for target MosquittoTest  which is not built by this project.
```

What is wrong with my cmake?

Answer (score 0):

I made mistake as these two lines need to be swapped.

```
target_link_libraries (MosquittoTest  mosquittopp)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(MosquittoTest MosquittoTest.cpp)
```